# Jenkins: Making project status depend on status of sub-projects

Tags: jenkins

I have a very simple Jenkins project which just calls four other Jenkins projects.

It seems it merely triggers the 4 builds and then immediately returns successfully.

Instead I'd like it to (eventually) set the project status as the worst of the 4 sub-projects, meaning if even one fails or is unstable, it will be set to fail or unstable.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403811/marking-upstream-jenkins-hudson-as-failed-if-downstream-job-fails

Comment: Ahh - thanks alot! Found the solution

Comment: If your solution was different to the related post I suggested, you might want to write it up and accept it as the answer to this question so that it's available for other users looking for the same information...

Answer (score 0):

Having selected '*Trigger/call builds on other projects*', I checked the '*Block until the triggered projects finish their builds*'